# Retrieving foreign key data when using linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am creating a basic rating system where users will enter a movie we have watched together and review it with a rating out of 10. I am struggling with how to get all the data to be retrieve into a view model(needs more work but dev testing currently).

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<EventViewModel>> GetEventWithReview(int id)
    {
        //not much here since I really am that stuck

        if (@event == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public  Event Event { get; set; }
    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

I have models:

Event:

```
    public class Event
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Event")]
        public int EventTypeID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }
        public string EventName { get; set; }
    }
```

EventType:

```
public class EventType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Review:

```
public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: try with `public List<Review> Reviews {get; set;} = new LIst<Review>();` in your Event entity. From there you have access of all reviews for this event like so                                                   `dataContext.Events.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(...).FirstOrDedfault();`

Comment: @spzvtbg im not sure how this helps my problem

Answer (score 0):

First, for a view model, this should reflect the data that the view wants to consume rather than containing the entities. Entities should always reflect the data state and that is often more information, and a relational model of the data which the view doesn't really need. As a general rule, an entity should never be passed outside of the scope of the DbContext where it was retrieved. EF does support detached entities but these need to be used with care and generally cause a lot more problems than they are worth in a project.

The goal of a view model is to compact the data that the view needs which improves over the wire performance, and also protects your system from revealing too much about it's data structure.

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ReviewViewModel> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class ReviewViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you go to select the event and it's reviews, you utilize something called Projection to translate the entities into the view models. This is done manually using `Select()` or can be automated by leveraging a library like AutoMapper which has a `ProjectTo<T>()` method.

Ideally your controller should have a DbContext injected, however as a starting point this example just scopes the DbContext in the request:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<EventViewModel>> GetEventWithReview(int id)
{
    using(var context = new YourAppDbContext())
    {
        var event = await context.Events
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .Select(x => new EventViewModel
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                EventType = x.EventType.Name,
                DateTime = x.DateTime,
                EventName = x.EventName,
                Reviews = x.Reviews
                    .Select(r => new ReviewModel
                    {
                       UserName = r.User.Name,
                       Rating = r.Rating
                    }).ToList()
            }).SingleAsync();

        return View(event);
    }
}
```

The projection here makes a few assumptions. For instance, if you have an EventType entity for the type of event, we may just want to display the event's Type as a string with the event so there's no need to create an event type view model, just `Select` the EventType.Name as "EventType" into the EventViewModel. ViewModels can flatten the relational data represented by the entities in this way to only pass the info the view can use rather than everything.  The same thing was done to get a user's name for the review (Assuming a User navigation property on the Review) so if you wanted to list reviews you could have a user name, comment, and rating. If not needed, then you could even just use a `List<int>` for ratings and use `x.Ratings.Select(r => r.Rating).ToList()` to just get the rating #'s. You can further refine the query if you want to do things like retrieve the most recent 10 ratings or such in the query expression with `OrderBy` and `Take`. EF will compose that all down to SQL to only pull back the data necessary to populate the view model. (Faster and less memory used on the server) The advantage of projection is that you can query values from the related entities via their navigation properties as you need in the query expression without having to worry about eager loading /w `Include()`. EF will work out building a query to populate whatever you extract via `Select`.